# Sematext logagent elasticsearch index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an index weekly in elastic search through log agent but logagent is unable to recognize any date patterns provided in their documentation, when I started debugging deep into it and I saw logagent only accepts DD/MM/YYYY pattern in the index name and nothing else.

https://github.com/sematext/logagent-js/blob/master/lib/plugins/output/elasticsearch.js

```
function applyDateFormatToIndex (index, data) {
  // support for time-based index patterns
  return index.replace(/YYYY|MM|DD/g, function (match) {
    if (match === 'YYYY') {
      return '' + data['@timestamp'].getFullYear()
    }
    if (match === 'MM') {
      return ('0' + (data['@timestamp'].getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2)
    }
    if (match === 'DD') {
      return ('0' + data['@timestamp'].getDate()).substr(-2)
    }
    return match
  })
}
```

Is there a way where I can customize this function inside YML file, so that this will be called instead of function from elasticsearch.js.

I can modify the core lib which is not a good practice. Also is there any other way where in the yml file itself i can call a function to  generate a index dynamically.

Snippet of my logagent config file.

```
output:
  secure-elasticsearch:
    # elasticsearch:
    module: elasticsearch
    url: ${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}

    httpOptions:
      key: /elastic-${LOG_ENV}-client.key
      cert: /elastic-${LOG_ENV}-client.crt
      ca: /elasticsearch.crt
      rejectUnauthorized: false

    # default index to use, for all logs that don't match any other configuration
    index: log-${LOG_ENV}-YYYY.MM.WW
    indices:
      dockerbeat-${LOG_ENV}-YYYY.MM.WW:
        - .*dockbeat\.json

  stdout: pretty
```

Answer (score 0):

In logstash:
Use YYYY.ww instead of it.
See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#sprintf

In logagent:
I think you can change `dateFormats` in this file.
https://github.com/sematext/logagent-js/blob/master/patterns.yml
Maybe it's on line 134.